# Multicollinearity in BLR

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Please I am exploring for multicollinearity in my data between socio-economic characteristics. I ran a collinearity diagnostic test and I have a conditional index of 6.235 which is less than 10. I believe this shows that multicollinearity is not a serious problem. On the other hand, when i check the variance proportions for the dimensions, I find that 3 of my predictor variables had greater than .60 loading on the same dimension. Does this suggest multicollinearity? All tolerance values were greater than .2 and VIF values were less than 5.

Therefore, what I am really interested in is thus: If I have VIF values < 5 and tolerance values > .2 but I have more than 1 variable with a loading of .50 and above on 1 of the dimensions, should I be concerned with the multicollinearity or should I ignore the variance loading since all other conditions were met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this does not suggest problematic collinearity, per the recommendations of David Belsley, who wrote the book on the subject.  (Actually, he wrote more than one).